# Failed to start an Appium session.Error was: Error: 'java -version' failed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

While running the application in Eclipse, I got error message as:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. 
>       (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: 
>       Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
>       Error: could not find java.dll Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

and in appium console it showing as Failed to start an Appium session, err was:

> Error: 'java -version' failed. Error: Command failed: 
>       Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
>       Error: could not find java.dll Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

I checked all the java path in system and looks its correct.

Comment: What class path have you set as JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: Under system variable I have set ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk                                                    JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65

Comment: ok looks fine , Also did you set JRE classpath?

Comment: Yes. I set JRE classpath.

Comment: What you set as JRE classpath? Kindly share.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Comment: do you have setup java home and android home in system variable ?

Answer (score 1):

please check in your mission  jdk, android and appium install or not for that use this commends.

use this commends
 go to cmd type:java---it will opened.after type 
               android when ever your check the android at the time sdk manager will be opened if u r see the cmd one message has displayed the message is xcopy is missing which is available in system32 folder copy the link and set the path before the jdk it will works

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK installation is broken, could be a lot of things:

- Probably you have x64 JDK, but in your Windows\System32 folder you have old java x32 java.exe, javaw.exe, javaws.exe, javap.exe and javac.exe You should delete them.

If not solved:

- delete Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment keys from registry

In any case after these steps you will need to reinstall JDK

Comment: I have followed your steps but still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: what is inside 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' ?

Comment: There are two folder 1.7 and 1.7.0_75.  sub folder For 1.7.0_75 is MSI

Comment: There are two folder 1.7 and 1.7.0_75.  sub folder For 1.7.0_75 is MSI      for 1.7 folder there are default,javahome=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7,microversion=0 and  runtimelib = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll

Comment: Hi Stanjer.. Still i'm facing same issue. please assist

Answer (score 0):

After research, I got solution for this issue. First uninstall all java in control panel and reinstall with latest version.